# Project a list of strings to a list of SQL statements

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings: `List<string> NameList = new List<string>()`

The list of names contains the following items:
`John Doe`, `Tom Jones`, `Bob Sinclair`

I want to project these items to a single joined string that looks like:

```
isnull(piv.[John Doe],0) [John Doe],
isnull(piv.[Tom Jones],0) [Tom Jones],
isnull(piv.[Bob Sinclair],0) [Bob Sinclair]
```

The above is a SQL statement that will be built using the program I am making. I do not need to execute the SQL, just return the joined list of names as a string in the aforementioned format.

Comment: What *exactly* did you expect `isnull(piv.[<NAME1>],0)` to do? Is that supposed to be the result of a function call?

Comment: Can you explain further, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is build a string to copy/paste later, you could use regex rather than c#. http://regexr.com/3divk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy to do with a little bit of LINQ and the `$` string interpolation operator. Try this:

```
var result = string.Join(
    $",{Environment.NewLine}",
    NameList.Select(x => $"isnull(piv.[{x}],0) [{x}]"));
```

`string.Join` will combine all the results with commas and newlines after each element.

`NameList.Select` projects each element to the format you need.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d54byv) with a fully working example. It creates this output:

```
isnull(piv.[John Doe],0) [John Doe],
isnull(piv.[Tom Jones],0) [Tom Jones],
isnull(piv.[Bob Sinclair],0) [Bob Sinclair]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var output = String.Join(",\n", NameList.Select(n => 
    string.Format("isnull(piv.[{0}],0) [{0}]", n)));
```

`String.Join` will take a list of strings and *join* them together with whatever separator you want to give it. `String.Format` is simply formatting a string by substituting `n` for `{0}`. So for each string in our list we use `Select` to *select* the formatted string and then we *join* that collection with `,\n`